How to estimate the number of parameters for CoreML models?
I'm working on comparing the impact of pruning on a CoreML model.
While I can easily measure changes in the file size (in kB), I'm struggling to estimate the changes in the number of model parameters, as CoreML does not offer a direct method like PyTorch's model.parameters(). How can I estimate or calculate the number of parameters in a pruned CoreML model?

There doesn't seem to be a direct and generic way of doing this other than to iterate through the layers and count the parameters depending on what kind of a layer it is.
For example,
Store a CoreML model with a convolution layer and a linear layer
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import coremltools as ct
import os

class SimpleNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SimpleNet, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 16, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(16 * 32 * 32, 10)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.conv1(x)
        x = self.relu(x)
        x = x.view(x.size(0), -1)
        x = self.fc1(x)
        return x

model = SimpleNet()

dummy_input = torch.rand(1, 3, 32, 32)
traced_model = torch.jit.trace(model, dummy_input)
coreml_model = ct.convert(
    traced_model,
    inputs=[ct.TensorType(name="input", shape=dummy_input.shape)]
)

model_name = "simple_net"
coreml_model.save(f"{model_name}.mlpackage")


This model has two layers: a conv and a linear layer. So we just iterate through the layers using model.get_spec().neuralNetwork.layers and for the conv layer, kernel_channels * output_channels * kernel_height * kernel_width gives the weights and output_channels is the number of bias terms. For the linear layer it's simply the number of inputs times the number of outputs.
def count_parameters(model):
    total_params = 0
    for layer in model.get_spec().neuralNetwork.layers:
        if layer.HasField('convolution'):
            conv = layer.convolution
            kernel_channels = conv.kernelChannels
            output_channels = conv.outputChannels
            kernel_height = conv.kernelSize[0]
            kernel_width = conv.kernelSize[1]
            params = kernel_channels * output_channels * kernel_height * kernel_width
            if conv.hasBias:
                params += output_channels
            total_params += params
        elif layer.HasField('innerProduct'):
            inner = layer.innerProduct
            input_channels = inner.inputChannels
            output_channels = inner.outputChannels
            params = input_channels * output_channels
            if inner.hasBias:
                params += output_channels
            total_params += params
    return total_params

coreml_params = count_parameters(coreml_model)
print(f"Total parameters: {coreml_params}")

It prints
Number of parameters in PyTorch model: 164298

If you directly count it on the Pytorch model through
total_params = sum(p.numel() for p in model.parameters())
print(f"Total parameters: {total_params}")

It matches
Total parameters: 164298

Not the best approach (and I hope someone else has a more generic approach) but it's a start.

Hi, whenever I run this script above the total parameter prints out 0. I am using python 3.10.11 and torch 2.5.0. What versions are you using?

hmm. Mine are Torch 2.5.0+cu121 and Python 3.10.12
Do you get 0 for both methods?

Only for the second method. I checked and found out I set the version to ios15, after I set it to ios12 it worked. Thanks. However I also discovered apple did not support post training pruning for ios12, and when the added that to ios15, we cannot access the neuralNetwork structure. So there is no way to compare pruning before and after on the coreml model, I can only prune in pytroch and compare the paraemters.
